# htaccess strip part of string in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule that redirects a specific path like

http://mev-hongkong.com/product/boardwalk-long-shorts/ to https://mothersenvogue.com.hk/product/boardwalk-long-shorts/

So my rule looks like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mev-hongkong\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^product/boardwalk-long-shorts(/.*)?$ https://mothersenvogue.com.hk/product/boardwalk-long-shorts$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE,QSD]
```

I also have a URL of the same path but the difference is that it has a "-2" on the end like

http://mev-hongkong.com/product/boardwalk-long-shorts**-2**/

What rule should I include on the original URL for me to be able to catch the "-2" on my old domain?

I tried making my RewriteRule like this (adding `.*` before the slash) but it didn't work.

```
 RewriteRule ^product/boardwalk-long-shorts(.*/.*)?$ https://mothersenvogue.com.hk/product/boardwalk-long-shorts$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE,QSD]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mev-hongkong\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^product/boardwalk-\w+-shorts(?:-[^/]+)?(/.*)?$ https://mothersenvogue.com.hk/product/boardwalk-long-shorts$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE,QSD]
```

`(?:-[^/]+)?` makes `-2/` an optional match

Comment: I applied it to this URL http://mev-hongkong.com/product/boardwalk-short-shorts-2/ so I just changed the path on the rewrite rule but it's only redirecting to https://mothersenvogue.com.hk/product/boardwalk-short-shorts-2/ which returns a 404 page. It's not landing to https://mothersenvogue.com.hk/product/boardwalk-short-shorts/ which is an active URL.

Comment: Great! This one worked perfectly! Thank you so much! Is there any way that I can follow you here on SO? :)

Comment: There is no follow feature on SO yet :) but you're welcome to connect with me to LInkedIn/Twitter (details mentioned in my SO profile)

Comment: Will do that! Thanks again! :)